# Is there a bug in the Game Closure Browser Simulator, such that the device.width and device.height are incorrect

Tags: html, gameclosure

I am using the Game Closure browser simulator which states that it is a 600x800 window.

I am printing the device size when the application starts:

```
console.log(device.width);
console.log(device.height);
```

It is displaying this as 320 x 480 (that is width x height):

```
320
480
```

The log also says this:

```
LOG platforms.browser.doc resize 320 480
```

The same thing happens when I use the facebook simulator.

The trouble is that I am trying to use device.width and device.height to scale my game to full size of the screen, regardless of the system.

If this is a known-bug, is there also a known work-around?

Thanks!

Comment: Has GameClosure closed up or abandoned ship? I sought out their IRC channel for support on an issue and no one was there.  It appears their twitter account is not very active and such..  Wondering if I should use something else..

Comment: Check the google group: game-closure-devkit@googlegroups.com

Comment: oh that's great thanks! Any luck with your issue?  Have you tried updating everything?  Basil and all..

Comment: I've not tried. I've actually haven't worked on my gameclosure project recently so I'm not sure if they updated this in basil. I'd like to get into it again some time though.